# The opposite of paper being a dead-tree

Tags: single-word-requests

In [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81263/postfix-or-suffix), John Y refers to a printed version of a book as "*dead-tree book*". I found that amuzing and started to wonder what the opposite of such term would be.

Of course, the popular term would be "*electronic book*". However, I'd like to retain the style of the original wording.

Comment: In the US, at least, most electric power is derived from fossil fuels, so an ebook, too, could legitimately be described as "dead-tree".

Comment: @StoneyB So the question "*will the book by in dead-tree or dead-tree?*" actually is grammatically and semantically correct?! It makes no sense, of course, and is as useful as a pocket on the back of a shirt but still... We need to specify whether the demise of said trees occurred during a cataclysmic events or industrial slashing.

Comment: Perhaps someone more technologically knowledgeable than I could suggest what resource it is that computers/displays exhaust -- rare earths?

Comment: A _live-tree book_? (Or would that just sound like those “L <3 J” scratchings kids make on bark?)

Comment: @StoneyB Patience, mostly. I suppose one could refer a dead Jobs book, but that's a bit dark.

Comment: How about a ***carbon-friendly*** copy of the book?

Comment: A _read-only_ book? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why *carbon-friendly*? Do I miss something obvious? I can't see any carbon related waste with printed books. Nor do I see any decrease in carbon footprint when using electronic dito.

Comment: @Neil That misses the witty aspect. Besides, one can edit most of the material electronically even it might get some hacking to do so.   :)

Comment: @Konrad: Postulate an ideal world where *everyone* has the capacity to read both dead-tree and e-books. And that someones write a fabulous book that everyone needs to read. I put it to you that the amount of carbon that will eventually end up messing up the environment would far greater if the publishers decide to go for hard copy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers QED! Agreed. However, it's a bit too far-fetched to use on people who aren't you or I (and possibly those who've read this particular thread).

Comment: @Konrad: We must console ourselves with the thought that relatively few trees would be harmed if every single person on the planet felt impelled to read our deathless prose here. (I'm assuming that most internet servers aren't powered by wood-burning stoves! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about  :-

"No-tree-dead book"

Answer (score 2):

How about a **live-wire book**? The e-book can't appear without electricity, and that's going to involve a live wire somewhere. (though we might need to allow a conductive trace on a circuit board to be signfied as a "wire")

The trouble with any "clever" alternative to the standard term "e-book", is that you're probably going to spend so much time explaining your alternative, that its snappiness is wasted.

Comment: Wiki. Even ebooks can be slow to make edits part of the text. Even "live" ebooks through services like amazon or safari can suffer this. A wiki is continually corrected and the edits are available to most readers very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

How about *tree-friendly books*, *paper-free books*, and *save-a-tree books*?